# problema ao usar o text to speech no python, problema com o path do windows

Tags: python, google, prompt

Eu segui esse tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries?hl=pt-br#client-libraries-install-python
Para fazer no python converter texto pra fala
Tudo foi bem, ate o comando

```
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
```

Ele não encontra o path, eu fiz  o que mandou o tutorial,

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\Usuario\ecc.json"
```

Mas ele continua reclamando que nao ta no path do windows.... E agora?

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema. Fiz assim:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "caminhoatesua/chave.json"
```